# Entry already exists - SVN commit error

Tags: svn

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Entry already exists
svn: 'url' is already under version control
```

This is the error given when I tried to Commit my project.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

1, move the dictory `'url'` to another place

2, svn update

3, move back the dictory

4, commit again

Comment: are you mean to remove the directory to another place which is not in this project? And then move it back after svn update?

Comment: oh no, I try your way, I have even remove the directory from the project, then I update whole project to Version, then I move back the directory, and commit whole project again. It still prompt me the same message with same url. What's wrong with this?

Comment: after update there must a 'url' directory in your project now. be sure there's no folder named .svn in your moved 'url' then copy it to the exist 'url'. do not remove the 'url' then move your 'url' to the project just use copy and replace the old files

Answer (score 1):

You have, most probably, copied the folder 'url' from another project that is already under subversion control. Verify this by inspecting the local disk folder (Eclipse: "workspace") and look for *hidden* folders named ".svn". You need to get rid of them.

- Either you can delete them all (every subdirectory should have one, too), then refresh your IDE view of the project, update to HEAD, add to subversion, commit.
- Or, at least this works in Eclipse, export the folder to an archive file, delete the folder 'url' from the project, and re-import it again from the archive - which should not contain any .svn-folders anymore. Again, update to HEAD, add to subversion, commit.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7278498)

1, move the dictory 'url' to another place (out of the svn controlled area)

2, svn update

**2.5 - svn commit!**

3, move back the dictory

4, commit again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing **all** .svn subdirectories (even that directly under NetbeansProjects) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you find .svn folder in your project root folder, manually delete it. That will unlink your files from svn. Now retry share project, it should be clean.